# How to run Python codes on one machine and access files of another machine via SSH?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh, jupyter-notebook, sshfs

Using my Mac laptop (A), I need to connect to a machine (B) with multiple GPUs to run Python codes (or Jupyter notebooks) using image files stored on another machine (C). What would be the best way to do that considering I will need to continue coding with A and running on B using images from C a lot in the future?

Comment: If you provide a list of promising solutions and ask which one would be the best, we call that an opinion based question here on Stack Overflow. There kind of questions are not allowed by the rules since they are attracting unwanted discussions. Please try to rewrite your question to concentrate on the core problem.

Comment: how do you want or could you access files on C from B, samba, netfs, ...., access B from A with VSC Remote extension (see doc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) to remotely connect to B, while in B you can use windows' remote connection to C to pass files:

[image]

Comment: The OP stated that machine A is a Mac and asks for SSH.